# How to add ellipsis to jQGrid column headerText

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, typescript, jqxgrid

How to add ellipsis to jQGrid column headerText.

Current Column Html Header for jqGrid is in like this :

```
<th id="ControlType" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 141px;">
<span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span>
<div id="jqgh_PageGrid_ControlType" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
    W'ñÝÃáèTÿpê !!!_W<span class="s-ico" style="display:none">
        <span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span>
        <span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span>
    </span>
```

"

I want to add ellipsis to this "W'ñÝÃáèTÿpê !!!_W"  in the header. 
I donot want to edit the jQGrid.js

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-th-column div { text-overflow: ellipsis }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `.s-ico` span tag inside `.ui-jqgrid-sortable` is set to `display:none` you can use a pseudo element to add ellipsis to the text:

```css
.ui-jqgrid-sortable:after {
  content:"...";
}
```

If the span will be toggled to `display:block` then you need to wrap the desired text into another element and apply the css rule to that element.

P.S: @Oleg's solution will work only if onlyi you set the heading `overflow` to `hidden` and the content actually goes out of it's container.

Comment: Yes by default icon is display block. When I add ellipsis to it. 
icon also gets toggled (not the desired option)

Wrapping only the text in a div will require changes in jqGrid.js (I believe that is where this html gets created). and I am not allowed to make changes in its jQgrid.js

Comment: Can we somehow  wrap "W'ñÝÃáèTÿpê !!!_W"  that text into a div using jquery, then it will be easy  a easy way out. :)

Comment: @RohitKumar Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery You can then wrap the text node using jQuery `wrap` method: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/